# Django Oscar - Adding Options to a Product Attribute

Tags: django-oscar

I want add some options to an Product attribute in django oscar.

Essentially I want to do the same as in the documentation but to turn it in to a full example. 
http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.6/topics/modelling_your_catalogue.html

So to do this am I correct in thinking that I need to use the customised model documentation to create a sub class of the Product and add these attributes to it.  http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.6/howto/how_to_customise_models.html

So if I took the above two documentation pages and put the code from each together I would get something like this?

```
from django.db import models

from oscar.apps.catalogue.abstract_models import AbstractProduct

class Product(AbstractProduct):
    video_url = models.URLField()

    language = AttributeOptionGroup.objects.create(name='Language')
    AttributeOption.objects.create(group=language,option='English')
    AttributeOption.objects.create(group=language,option='Croatian')

    klass = ProductClass.objects.create(name='foo', slug='bar')
    ProductAttribute.objects.create(
        product_class=klass,
        name='Language',
        code='language',
        type='option',
        option_group=language)

from oscar.apps.catalogue.models import *
```

Update 26/04/2018:
https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/pull/2448

Fix in Django Oscar to add ability to add option group using the dashboard. 
I think I need to check my Django version as I can not see this option in my dashboard.

Comment: This was added in version 1.6, which is currently out as an RC (`pip install django-oscar==1.6rc1`).

Answer (score 2):

> Product attributes let you set additional data on a product without having to customise the underlying Django models.

As per the [documentation](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.6/topics/modelling_your_catalogue.html#product-attributes), no, you don't have to override the default `catalogue.Product` model. You should instead create `ProductClass` that has the `ProductAttribute` that has the `OptionsGroup` you want.

You should only override the default models in case you want this functionality for all your products (irrespective of their `ProductClass`).

Basically, you can either do what you've done inside your custom `Product` class, and put it a migration, or do the same via the dashboard. Overriding the `Product` class is not needed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As per update - checking django version as I can not see the ability to add options group in the dashboard.

Comment: Oh okay, [the commit](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/commit/956b5b7853f46ca01a63ef74f4ff44e4d7456cc0) suggests it was there in 1.6rc1 so, it should be there in 1.6